# App crashing in push notification

Tags: android, xml, push-notification

I just want to create sample app for push notification but getting error , this is my activity. App crashing in the line shown below comment.

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
EditText ed1,ed2,ed3;
public NotificationManager notificationManager;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ed1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
    ed2=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    ed3=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText3);
    Button b1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);

    b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String tittle = ed1.getText().toString().trim();
            String subject = ed2.getText().toString().trim();
            String body = ed3.getText().toString().trim();

            Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(MainActivity.this);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0, new Intent(), 0);
            builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable. menu1)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                    .setContentTitle(tittle)
            .setContentText(subject)
            .setSubText(body);

            Notification notification = builder.getNotification();
            //App crashing while executing this line
            notificationManager.notify(0, notification);
        }
    });
}}
```

Here is my layout XML file.

```
<RelativeLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" 
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" 
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" 
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="TESTING"
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:textSize="35dp"
    android:textColor="#ff16ff01" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/textView2"
    android:hint="Name" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/editText2"
    android:hint="Subject"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/editText" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/editText3"
    android:hint="Body"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/editText2" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Notification"
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText3"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" /></RelativeLayout>
```

Now the app is not crashing but notification is not displaying when am    clicking the button

**LOGCAT for error**

```
12-24 14:34:28.491  20905-20905/com.example.siva.push D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Enabling debug mode 0
12-24 14:34:28.571  20905-20905/com.example.siva.push I/Timeline﹕ Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@41d33cd8 time:125753735
12-24 14:34:32.701  20905-20905/com.example.siva.push W/IInputConnectionWrapper﹕ beginBatchEdit on inactive InputConnection
12-24 14:34:32.701  20905-20905/com.example.siva.push W/IInputConnectionWrapper﹕ endBatchEdit on inactive InputConnection
12-24 14:34:33.881  20905-20905/com.example.siva.push W/IInputConnectionWrapper﹕ beginBatchEdit on inactive InputConnection
12-24 14:34:33.881  20905-20905/com.example.siva.push W/IInputConnectionWrapper﹕ endBatchEdit on inactive InputConnection
12-24 14:34:35.151  20905-20905/com.example.siva.push V/AudioManager﹕ playSoundEffect   effectType: 0
12-24 14:34:35.151  20905-20905/com.example.siva.push V/AudioManager﹕ querySoundEffectsEnabled...
12-24 14:34:42.641  20905-20905/com.example.siva.push V/AudioManager﹕ playSoundEffect   effectType: 0
12-24 14:34:42.641  20905-20905/com.example.siva.push V/AudioManager﹕ querySoundEffectsEnabled...
12-24 14:34:47.261  20905-20905/com.example.siva.push V/AudioManager﹕ playSoundEffect   effectType: 0
12-24 14:34:47.261  20905-20905/com.example.siva.push V/AudioManager﹕ querySoundEffectsEnabled...
12-24 14:34:52.411  20905-20905/com.example.siva.push V/AudioManager﹕ playSoundEffect   effectType: 0
12-24 14:34:52.411  20905-20905/com.example.siva.push V/AudioManager﹕ querySoundEffectsEnabled...
```

Comment: Anybody please help me , thanks in advance...

Comment: your variable notifcationmanger is null. It is never initiailized

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Initialize your NotificationManager variable

```
NotificationManager notificationManager= (NotificationManager)MainActivity.this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
```

**Note:** `getNotification()` is deprecated. Better use `builder.build()` instead

Comment: Thank you @Kunu , Now app is not crashing but notification is not displaying when am clicking the button.